Determine the minimal polynomial of $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F^n})$ defined by $ T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (\sum x_i , \ldots, \sum x_i)$
The following exercise come from Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th edition, Sheldon Axler (I removed parts of the exercise that do not pertain to my question).

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer and $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F^n})$ is defined by
$$
T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1 + \cdots + x_n, \ldots, x_1 + \cdots + x_n)
$$
Find the minimal polynomial of $T$.


Here, $\mathbb{F}$ is either the set of real or complex numbers. I followed one of Axler's mentioned approaches where we choose a $v \in \mathbb{F^n}$ and consider the equation
$$
c_0v + c_1Tv + \cdots + c_{n-1}T^{n-1} = -T^nv
$$
Then we use the standard basis of $\mathbb{F^n}$ to get the matrix of $T$ to find the expressions of $Tv, \ldots, T^{n-1}v, T^nv$.

Here's my attempt. I choose the vector $e_1 := (1, 0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{F^n}$. Using the standard basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $\mathbb{F^n}$, the matrix of $T$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix whose entries are all $1$, that is,
$$
\mathcal{M}(T) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 
\vdots & & \vdots \\  1 & \cdots & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This implies
\begin{align}
Te_1 &= e_1 + \cdots + e_n \\
T^2e_1 &= n(e_1 + \cdots + e_n) \\
&\vdots \\
T^{n}e_1 &= n^{n-1}(e_1 + \cdots + e_n) = n^{n-1}Te_1
\end{align}
That is, $T^{n}e_1 = n^{n-1}Te_1$, implying the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $z^n + n^{n-1}z$.

Questions:

Did I get the correct expression for the minimal polynomial?
Do I need to actually show that $z^n + n^{n-1}z$ is indeed the minimal polynomial, that is, do I have to show $T^n + n^{n-1}T = 0$ and it's of smallest degree? Or does the procedure above take that into account implicitly?


actually $T^2 = nT$  and minimal is $z^2 - nz$

@WillJagy did you mean to write $T^n$ instead of $T^2$?

no..................Tell you what. The matrix $M$ is all $1'$s.  What is $M^2 ?$

@WillJagy a matrix whose entries are all $n$

Good. Since $M$ itself has all $1's$   this means $M^2 = n M.$

@WillJagy okay makes sense. And knowing that the eigenvalues  values are $0$ and $n$, and that the zeroes of the minimal polynomial are the eigenvalues of $T$, I see how $z^2 -nz$ makes sense. But I don’t understand why my procedure above didn’t lead me to that.

I put an answer based on your way of writing this. No matrices as such

From your expressions
$$ Te_1 = e_1 + \cdots + e_n  $$
$$ Te_2 = e_1 + \cdots + e_n  $$
....
$$ Te_{n-1} = e_1 + \cdots + e_n  $$
$$ Te_n = e_1 + \cdots + e_n  $$
Add up all $n$ equations, the left hand side becomes
$$ T(e_1 + \cdots + e_n)$$
while the right hand sides are all the same, the sum is just $n$ of them.  So far
$$ T(e_1 + \cdots + e_n) = n(e_1 + \cdots + e_n)$$
However, we know that $(e_1 + \cdots + e_n) = T e_j$  for every $j,$  substitute on both sides to get
$$T(T e_j)  = nT e_j   $$
or
$$   T^2 e_j = nT e_j    $$
or
$$  (T^2 - nT) e_j = 0$$
As this is true for each basis vector, we get
$$ T^2 - nT = 0$$

Ah, perfect. Thank you for your time.

Your expression for the minimal polynomial is not correct – in fact, $z^n + n^{n-1}z$ does not even annihilate $T$. This is because we can factor the polynomial as
$$z(z^{n-1} + n^{n-1})$$
and notice that the roots of this polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ will be $0$ and
$$\begin{cases}
-ne^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n-1}} & \text{if } n \text{ is even}\\
ine^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n-1}} & \text{if } n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}.$$
However, the only eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$ and $n$.
As Will Jagy has noted, the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $z^2-nz$; the easiest way to arrive at this is probably to either look at the matrix in the standard basis or to find that $0$ and $n$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ and then check that the simplest possible polynomial i.e. $z(z-n) = z^2 - nz$ actually annihilates $T$.
The issue in your computation is twofold: firstly, there is an arithmetic mistake in the translation from $T^ne_1 = n^{n-1}Te_1$ to $T^ne_1 + n^{n-1} Te_1$ (there should be a $-$ here rather than a $+$). However, the main issue is connected to your second question: while $T^n - n^{n-1}T = 0$, there are extra factors in this polynomial which do not correspond to eigenvalues of $T$. Thus you do need to check that the polynomial you have is actually minimal. Otherwise this process would imply that the minimal polynomial is always of degree $n$, which is not true.

Thank you for your response; finally had some time to go over it! This also cleared some things up for me.

This is $T = 11^T$, which in an orthogonal basis $\{1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ has matrix representation $\text{diag}(n, 0, 0, \dots, 0)$. Hence $p(z) = (z - n)z$ is the minimal polynomial. In general, you can read off the minimal polynomial from the Jordan form of the matrix.
